# Subclasses of UICollectionviewcell fail to be implemented as generics

Tags: swift, generics, polymorphism, uicollectionviewcell

I'm looking to dynamically crate some collectionviews.

When calling my factory function I want to pass it a Subclassed Type of a UICollectionViewCell. I'm using Typed generics to get this done.
However the compiler is stopping me and making me question my understanding of polymorphism in Swift.

Could anybody shed some light on the matter?

My CustomCell

```
public class DiscoverySmallCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    public var mainView : DiscoveryNavigationCard


    public init(image: UIImage) {
        self.mainView = DiscoveryNavigationCard(largeImage: image)
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setup()
    }

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.mainView = DiscoveryNavigationCard()
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        setup()
    }

    public init() {
        self.mainView = DiscoveryNavigationCard()
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setup()
    }

    private func setup(){
        self.addSubview(mainView)
        pinToParent(view: mainView, parent: self)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

My Controller:
Function Signature in question:

```
    private func createColletionViewAndContainer <T>(identifier: String, cellSize: CGSize, cellType: T) where T: UICollectionViewCell {
```

Calling fucntion:

```
    private func setupCollectionViews(items: [DiscoveryItem]) {

        for item in items {
            let category = item.category
            switch category {
            case "hospital", "favourites":
                self.createColletionViewAndContainer(identifier: category, cellSize: LocalLayout.smallCellSize, cellType: DiscoverySmallCollectionCell )

            default :
                self.createColletionViewAndContainer(identifier: category, cellSize: LocalLayout.largeCellSize, cellType: DiscoveryLargeCollectionCell)

            }
        }
        setup()
    }
```

Comment: Try just:
...
self.createColletionViewAndContainer(identifier: category, cellSize: LocalLayout.smallCellSize, cellType: DiscoverySmallCollectionCell.self)
...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately the compiler still complains:

Cannot convert value of type 'DiscoveryLargeCollectionCell.Type' to expected argument type 'UICollectionViewCell'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After A little bit of reading in the excellent: *IOS 12 Programming fundamentals with Swift*  i've caught the issue. It was Syntax-related.

The argument cellType needed to be: T.Type, not: T.

The correct signature is:

```
  private func createColletionViewAndContainer  <T>(identifier: String, cellSize: CGSize, cellType: T.Type) where T: UICollectionViewCell {}
```

The caller should supply cellType with .self appended:

```
(signature....cellType: SomeClass.self)
```

So if Matt Neuburg is out there: I'll accept you answer :P

And a big thanks to everybody that responded!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to setup reusable cell with generics this is one simply mode:

**First**

setup generic a cell, in this example it takes only one argument, but you can do whatever you want

```
class GenericCollectionViewCell<U>: UICollectionViewCell {
    var item: U!
}
```

**Second**

create a `UIViewController` that accepts your generic cell

```
class GenericViewController<T: GenericCollectionViewCell<U>, U>: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    var items: [U] = []

    fileprivate let cellReuseIdentifier = "GenericCollectionViewCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        collectionView.register(T.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? GenericCollectionViewCell<U> else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
        cell.item = items[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Third**

subclass your generic cell and do all your setup

```
class MySublclassedCollectionViewCell: GenericCollectionViewCell<Whatever> {
  override var item: Whatever! { // see that item becomes of type Whatever
      didSet {
        // setup your cell from here
      }
  }
}
```

**Final**

sublcass the `GenericViewController` and the job is done

```
class SublcassedViewController: GenericViewController<GenericCollectionViewCell, Whatever> {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

       self.items = // setup items 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, this is a bit too much for my specific purposes.  I only want to register a Generic cell in my factory function. I've solved it,